# using SSIS loading xml and having memory problems

Tags: xml, memory, ssis

I am importing a very complex XML to Sal server using SSIS. I am using the same schema for over 2000 XML files. I have a For Loop looping through all of the files in a folder.

**Problem:** While the first file takes about 0.5 sec to load, by file 300 loading takes about 12 sec and then progressively gets worse.

I have tried to clear the memory by adding a step

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
```

in the For Each loop but this does not help.

Comment: Do all the XML files contain about the same amount of data or is file 300 way larger than the preceding?

Comment: they do not all contain the same amount. but some have more and some have less and the is random. they do not get progressively bigger.

Comment: You might want to read [Top 10 SSIS Best Practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2013/09/16/top-10-sql-server-integration-services-best-practices.aspx). This will give you some information on finding out what might be happening with the SSIS buffer pools (Not SQL buffers)